# Android OAuth consent screen stuck in white loading screen

Tags: android, google-api

I have been trying to solve this for many days now, to no avail. I want to use the google-fit APIs, and it seems that I am getting stuck in an infinite loading screen during the OAuth Consent flow.

For the consent screen I have:

- Gone to the google cloud console
- I have enabled Google Fit
- Setup the OAuth consent screen with a logo, company name, etc
- Added scope that I need
- Added me as a test user

I also created the credentials:

- I got the SHA-1 of my debug Keystore, which is used to sign the test version of the application
- I created a new Android credential, giving the SHA-1 and the package name from the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The code I use is just the android sample for Google Fit here here: https://github.com/android/fit-samples/tree/main/BasicHistoryApiKotlin

Everything works fine when the OAuth consent screen is in test mode.

However, when I put the Oauth Consent screen in **Production mode**, it stops working.

I get stuck in this screen, which appears immediately after selecting the user account.
[image]

By taking a look at the logs, I see this error:

```
2021-10-22 17:44:53.737 2571-3763/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NEED_REMOTE_CONSENT. App: com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write
```

NOTE: This happens only when submitting the OAuth screen for production. In test, it works correctly. Normally I should be able to see this screen https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en (since I am not verified) and be able to proceed after clicking a button. But this does not happen.

NOTE 2: I know this has appeared multiple times in stack overflow, but my case has to do with my consent screen in **production** mode (which should still work according to Google with a warning), even if Google hasn't approved it.

I would appreciate any help the community could give me. Has anyone encountered issues like this when going into production?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I had the same problem as you, where this started occurring only when I put the app into production. It turned out the scope I requested in the app was broader than the one I requested in Google Cloud Console. In the app, I was requesting full access to Google Photos, while in Google Cloud Console I was just requesting read access. For some reason, this wasn't a problem in testing but was in production. So I would double-check to make sure that the scopes match.